# Adobe Audition CS6 Crashing

Tags: audio, cs6

I am running Adobe Audition CS6. Each time that I try to work in my project, it continues to crash due to a “fatal error”. I have reset the preferences, but it continues to crash. I am running windows 7 professional. Here is the Log, the last entry in the log looks to be the culprit.

```
 Ticks = 107781      <1556> <AuLog.Error> <5> Unhandled exception caught in aui:ErrorManager::ExecuteFunctionWithTopLevelExceptionHandler()
```

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1):

An und handled execption is never a good sign. That means its either a bug in the application, in that case there is usually not much you can do other than sending Adobe a detailed report about the crash. Another possibility can be a malfunctioning driver or a hardware failure.

Maybe you have recently installed something or updated a driver? Reverse that installation and see if the problem persists.
Also check your RAM, something that is the cause for a lot of random crashes is corrupt RAM.

You can check the health of you RAM with a tool like [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso). Best to run it over night as it needs many iterations to really ensure healthy RAM.